# "Basic Gesture Detect" from Android SDK sample - runtime error?

Tags: android-fragments

After compile "Basic Gesture Detect" inside Android SDK's "android-18" (input/gesture etc) samples directory:

```
cmp=com.example.android.basicgesturedetect/.MainActivity} from pid 866
D/audio_hw_primary(  180): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
D/ACDB-LOADER(  180): ACDB -> send_afe_cal
D/dalvikvm(  593): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 680K, 16% free 24235K/28556K, paused 77ms, total 78ms
D/dalvikvm(22048): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/ActivityManager(  593): Start proc com.example.android.basicgesturedetect for activity com.example.android.basicgesturedetect/.MainActivity: pid=22048 uid=10082 gids={50082}
D/AndroidRuntime(22048): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(22048): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4189bba8)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(22048): Process: com.example.android.basicgesturedetect, PID: 22048
E/AndroidRuntime(22048): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.basicgesturedetect/com.example.android.basicgesturedetect.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at com.example.android.basicgesturedetect.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(22048): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.android.common.SimpleTextFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:409)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    ... 21 more
E/AndroidRuntime(22048): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.common.SimpleTextFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.basicgesturedetect-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.basicgesturedetect-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
E/AndroidRuntime(22048):    ... 24 more
W/ActivityManager(  593):   Force finishing activity com.example.android.basicgesturedetect/.MainActivity
D/dalvikvm(  593): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 757K, 16% free 24159K/28556K, paused 78ms, total 78ms
D/dalvikvm(  593): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 581K, 16% free 24132K/28556K, paused 72ms, total 72ms
W/ActivityManager(  593): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{425c3790 u0 com.example.android.basicgesturedetect/.MainActivity t39 f}
I/Process (22048): Sending signal. PID: 22048 SIG: 9
W/InputMethodManagerService(  593): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@428b9028 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@428f4210
I/ActivityManager(  593): Process com.example.android.basicgesturedetect (pid 22048) has died.
```

can someone explain to me the cause of the error?

My gradle is version 1.6 from Gradle, and compiled the BasicGesture sample using "gradle build" and installed it into my Nexus 7.

Answer (score 0):

The error was found to arise from a older gradle version, now I change it to gradle 1.10 and it build fine:

```
gradle build
:BasicGestureDetectSample:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:preBuild
:BasicGestureDetectSample:preDebugBuild
:BasicGestureDetectSample:checkDebugManifest
:BasicGestureDetectSample:prepareDebugDependencies
:BasicGestureDetectSample:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:validateDebugSigning
:BasicGestureDetectSample:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:preReleaseBuild
:BasicGestureDetectSample:checkReleaseManifest
:BasicGestureDetectSample:prepareReleaseDependencies
:BasicGestureDetectSample:compileReleaseAidl
:BasicGestureDetectSample:compileReleaseRenderscript
:BasicGestureDetectSample:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:BasicGestureDetectSample:mergeReleaseAssets
:BasicGestureDetectSample:generateReleaseResValues
:BasicGestureDetectSample:generateReleaseResources
:BasicGestureDetectSample:mergeReleaseResources
:BasicGestureDetectSample:processReleaseManifest
:BasicGestureDetectSample:processReleaseResources
:BasicGestureDetectSample:generateReleaseSources
:BasicGestureDetectSample:compileReleaseJava
:BasicGestureDetectSample:lintVitalRelease SKIPPED
:BasicGestureDetectSample:compileReleaseNdk
:BasicGestureDetectSample:preDexRelease
:BasicGestureDetectSample:dexRelease
:BasicGestureDetectSample:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:BasicGestureDetectSample:packageRelease
:BasicGestureDetectSample:assembleRelease
:BasicGestureDetectSample:assemble
:BasicGestureDetectSample:compileLint
:BasicGestureDetectSample:lint
Ran lint on variant debug: 10 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 10 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:/sda3/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/input/BasicGestureDetect/BasicGestureDetectSample/build/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to /sda3/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/input/BasicGestureDetect/BasicGestureDetectSample/build/lint-results.xml
:BasicGestureDetectSample:check
:BasicGestureDetectSample:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 27.809 secs
```